# Downloading The attachcament gives Blob result in csv`

Tags: apex, lightning, attachment

I have made a lightning component to download the attachment associated with a custom object record. The downloading is working perfectly, however the downloaded file is opened with blob data. The same thing is happening with .jpeg files.

Server Side Controller :-

```
@AuraEnabled 
    public static List<Attachment> fetchSellSheets(String PgmId){ 
        System.debug('Entering fetchSellSheets-->'+PgmId);
        return [SELECT Id,Name, CreatedBy.Name, ContentType FROM Attachment WHERE  ParentId =:PgmId AND Name LIKE 'SS %' LIMIT 1000];
    }
```

Lightning Component :-

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction"
                access="global"
                controller="OPLOW_UploadedSellSheetsController">
    <!--aura doInit handler--> 
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <!--aura attributes-->  
    <aura:attribute name="selectedDocumentId" type="string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="lstContentDoc" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isRecords" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="pgmId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="delId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isArchived" type="Boolean" default ="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isConfirmModal" type="boolean" />

    <!-- Custom DataTable to Display List Of Available ContentDocuments Start-->  
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isRecords}">
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                    <th class="slds-text-title_caps" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Title">Title</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="slds-text-title_caps" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Created By">Created By</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="" scope="col">
                        <div class="" title="">&nbsp;</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstContentDoc}" var="CD">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!CD.desc}">
                                <a href="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+CD.Id}" target="_blank">{!CD.desc}</a>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!CD.CreatedBy.Name}">{!CD.CreatedBy.Name}</div>
                        </th>
                        <td> 
                            <button onclick="{!c.onClickDelete}" class="slds-button slds-button_icon" id="{!CD.Id}" title="Delete Record" disabled="{!v.isArchived}">
                                <lightning:icon iconName="utility:delete" size="x-small" alternativeText="Remove"/>
                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Remove</span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>  
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Client Side Controller :-

```
fetchData : function(component, event, helper) {
        debugger;
        var programId = component.get("v.pgmId");
        var action = component.get("c.fetchSellSheets");
        action.setParams({
            'PgmId': programId
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            var  records = response.getReturnValue();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                if(records.length){
                 for(var i =0;i<records.length;i++){
                        records[i].desc = records[i].Name+'.'+records[i].ContentType;
                    }
                }
                component.set('v.lstContentDoc', records);
                if(!records.length){
                    component.set('v.isRecords', false);
                }
            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // do something
            }
                else if (state === "ERROR") {
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    if (errors) {
                        if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                            console.log("Error message: " + 
                                        errors[0].message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("Unknown error");
                    }
                }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    },
```

Is there any way to convert that blob data into readable format.
Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the minimal required code to look into the issue you are facing?

Comment: @sanketkumar Added the code, Thanks!

Comment: I could not replicate the issue. File is having correct data when it is downloaded from your component. Did you checked the attachment first, weather they contains correct data or not?

Comment: File is getting saved with body as blob , as it is getting created from apex.